# Spring Injected Class

Tags: java, spring

I am new to working with Spring and I just joined a team of developers that is utilizing it for the product we are working on.  I am beginning to understand IoC.  However, I am flummuxed on one particular point.  I have searched for an answer, but have been unable to find anything.

The class I am looking at has the `@Controller` annotation set on it. One of the methods has the `@RequestMapping` annotation. The method signature of this particular method contains a parameter for one of my company's proprietary classes.  This proprietary class does not have any annotations on it for Spring nor is it listed in the Spring configuration file.

So, my question is: **how does that parameter get injected when there isn't anything to help the framework identify it?**

I suspect that it is able to do this because on the previous transaction the proprietary class is added to the Model via `ModelAndView.addObject()`, but I was hoping someone could confirm or deny.

The particular scenario is this:

1. user requests login page
2. `addObject(proprietaryClass)`
3. user presented with login page
4. user clicks button to login
5. method is called with proprietary class in method signature.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Is the particular method parameter annotated with `@ModelAttribute`?

Comment: No, there isn't any annotations on the method parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring is smart... real smart.  It can look at the names of the request parameters and map them to POJOs by field name.  For instance, if your user has a "first" and "last" fields, you could pass in user.first=Joe&user.last=Blow and it would attempt to set the "first" and "last" properties of your user object.  Have a look at http://www.jpalace.org/docs/technotes/spring/mvc-params.html specifically the section named Binding Domain Objects.

Another option is that they have implemented a converter, or converter factory.  In my project I implemented a generic ConverterFactory that handles any of my database entities, takes a Long and converts it to the materialized entity by looking it up by id.

Comment: Would the first suggestion require Spring to be aware of the User class?

Comment: I am looking into the possibility of a converter.  It looks like there may be some references to converters in the Spring configuration file.

Comment: The first suggestion does not require spring to be aware of the User class. It just uses reflection.

Comment: OK... after looking at this more in depth, I think I understand what is happening.  And correct me if I am wrong in this.  Like you said, Spring is real smart, but I didn't realize how smart.  What I am looking at is the login page is a form.  What I think is happening is Spring is automatically mapping the form values to the class.  And, it is doing this without the need for developers to specify it in the Spring configuration file or by using an annotation.  Is that how forms work in Spring?

Comment: Spring embraces convention over configuration.  The convention is that if the form input name matches the java POJO field name (obtained via reflection) then it can map it without further configuration.

Comment: Sure thing.  It also works with regular parameters too.  For instance a String or Long parameter named "myId" would match an html input field named "myId", so it's not just POJO fields.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your beans configuration you'll find a conversion service bean. If the other developers are nice, they will name it something like "ConverterFactory", and it will probably extend `org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean`. You can also grep the codebase for `org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry`.

This is described in the [Spring Reference Manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert).

Comment: I just did a search for those and came up empty handed.

Comment: I am looking into the possibility of a converter.  It looks like there may be some references to converters in the Spring configuration file.

Comment: OK... after looking at this more in depth, I think I understand what is happening.  And correct me if I am wrong in this.  What I am looking at in the login page is a form.  What I think is happening is Spring is automatically mapping the form values to the class.  And, it is doing this without the need for developers to specify it in the Spring configuration file or by using an annotation.  Is that how forms work in Spring?